# check other commerce pane validation error

Tags: commerce, forms

I am work on commerce pane, in `hook_pane_checkout_form_submit($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order)`  I call a function to do something in pane sumbit,

something like

```
function hook_pane_checkout_form_submit($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {

  do_update_something($user);
}
```

but when I am not fill another pane like address , my function called,
How can I prevent submit when there is error (validation in another panes) in other panes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check errors before call your function

```
function hook_pane_checkout_form_submit($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
if (!(form_get_errors()){
 do_update_something($user);
}

}
```